# Obout easy menu not working properly in firefox only

Tags: asp.net

I am using obout easy menu in my asp.net 3.5 webapplication.  Its working nicely for IE-9, Chrome and Safari-5.

But in case of Mozilla Firefox, obout easy menu is displayed correctly. When I click on one of four easy menu tabs, its not working although cursor becomes hand on mouseover.

Please help me find the problem.

Comment: You did not mentioned about version of obout menu. Also this link http://www.obout.com/em/ht_howto.aspx?id=a16 suggest that they have tested it in FireFox, so did you make sure that everything else on your application part ( like invoking the menu, script tags etc) is fit and fine?

Comment: the version of obout easy menu is 3.11.1.1 its working well on ie, chrome, safari but visible on firefox and not working.....

Answer (score 0):

Since i was facing above problem with firefox browser, therefore when i studied compatibility issues regarding browsers. I found something which is not valid for firefox which included Document.All.Tags("NAME") after replacing it with document.getTagsbyName("Name"), i saw that obout easy menu are working properly. thanks for all for your kind considerations regarding this.

Really i found this platform more helpfull beyound my thoughts, from onward i will use this forum frequently.

Best of Luck Guys.

Arshad